Not able to Find Swift Ui Class from .mm class
From MyBridge.mm file Xcode is not able to locate TranslationWrapper in below code
I have a folder structure like this :

main.cpp
    #include <iostream>
#include "TranslationConnector.h"
#import "MyBridge.h" 

int main() {
    std::string textToTranslate = "Hello, world!";
    
    NSString *translatedText = [MyBridge translateToSpanish:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:textToTranslate.c_str()]];

        // Convert the result back to C++ string
        std::string result = [translatedText UTF8String];

        // Now 'result' contains the translated text
        std::cout << result << std::endl;

        return 0;
}

TranslationWrapper.swift
    import Foundation

@objc class TranslationWrapper: NSObject {
    @objc static func translateToSpanish(_ text: String) -> String {
        // This is where you perform the translation.
        // For demonstration, let's assume it simply appends " in Spanish" to the text.
        return text + " in Spanish"
    }
}

MyBridge.h
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyBridge : NSObject

+ (NSString *)translateToSpanish:(NSString *)text;

@end

MyBridge.mm
    #import "MyBridge.h"
#import "TranslationDemo1-Swift.h" // Import the Swift module (adjust module name)

@implementation MyBridge

+ (NSString *)translateToSpanish:(NSString *)text {
    return [TranslationWrapper translateToSpanish:text];
}

@end

